# First time using a separate class (.cs) file for a method

Tags: c#

Sorry for posting this wall of garbage code :( I didn't want to leave anything out! Im still new and got a little ahead of myself. I wanted to put the "switch case" in a new class so I could reference it faster while also learning to make a new class file. Unfortunately I ran into one bug after another and I couldn't figure out why. The main issue i had is that when I call the case number in the main method, it only returns the string.

Ex. I want the output to be:
 "Well [user created name], are you ready to begin your journey to the edge of the world?"

It seems there is an issue with the two classes communicating with eachother.
I have made it worse throwing "public static" at everything to try to make it work. I would really appreciate the help.

```
using System;
using Test;

public class Scripts
{
    public Program p { get; set; }

    public void Script(int s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case 1:
                p.output = "Quest to the edge of the world!";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 2:
                p.output = "Hello! I am your instructor. What is your name apprentice?";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case :
                p.output = p.name + " you say? My, what a strange name.";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 4:
                p.output = "Well " + p.name + ", are you ready to begin your journey to the edge of the world?";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 5:
                p.output = " (y)Yes on (n)No";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 6:
                p.output = "OK! Before we go lets go over our gear. What should we prioritize? (1)Magic, (2)Melee, or (3)Ranged?";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 7:
                p.output = "Well I'll just come back tomorrow then.";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 8:
                p.output = "I'm sorry... that's not an option.";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 9:
                p.output = "I'm pretty good at " + p.combatStyle + " combat myself, I'll be sure to teach you everything I know.";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 10:
                p.output = "OK! Let's hit the road and make camp at sundown.";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 11:
                p.output = "Chapter " + p.chapter;
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 12:
                p.output = p.name + ", wake up!Were under attack by a couple of goblins!";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 13:
                p.output = "I guess this is the perfect chance to teach you a new" + p.form + "called";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 14:
                p.output = "It makes quick work of their health, but your" + p.energyBar + " will go down just as fast so use it wisely!";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 15:
                p.output = "I'll take care of the one on the right, you engage the one on the left.";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;
            case 16:
                p.output = "Press (f) to enter combat. Then press (1) to make an attack";
                p.WriteLine();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}

using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public Scripts s { get; set; }
        // Class Global Variables
        public static string input;
        public static string output;
        public static string name = "bob";
        private static string yes = "y";
        private static string no = "n";
        private static string option1 = "1";
        private static string option2 = "2";
        private static string option3 = "3";
        private static string pathA;
        private static string pathB;
        private static string pathC;
        public static string combatStyle;
        private static string weapon;
        public static string chapter = "Zero";
        public static string form;
        public static string energyBar;
        private static string healthBar;
        Program p = new Program();
        public static string[] numbers = new string[] { "One","Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        private static int mp = 100;
        private static int stamina = 100;
        private static int script;



        //ReadLine & WriteLine Methods
        private static void ReadLine()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - 110) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void WriteLine()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - output.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }

        //Next Chapter Screen
        private static void nextChapter()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.Clear();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            output = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
            WriteLine();
            //output = script[12] + chapter;
            WriteLine();
            Console.Beep();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.Clear();



        }

        //Yes or No Decision
        private static void YesNo()
        {
            while (input != yes && input != no)
            {
                ReadLine();
                if (input == yes)
                {
                    output = pathA;
                    WriteLine();
                }
                else if (input == no)
                {
                    output = pathB;
                    WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    //output = script[8];
                    WriteLine();
                }
            }
            input = "";
        }

        //Multiple Choice Decision
        private static void Choice()
        {
            while (input != option1 && input != option2 && input != option3)
            {
                ReadLine();
                if (input == option1)
                {
                    output = pathA;
                    WriteLine();
                }
                else if (input == option2)
                {
                    output = pathB;
                    WriteLine();
                }
                else if (input == option3)
                {
                    output = pathC;
                    WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    //output = //script[8];
                    //WriteLine();
                }
            }
            input = "";
        }

        //Combat Loop
        private static void combatLoop()
        {
            if (input == "f")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //output = script[8];
                WriteLine();
                combatLoop();
            }
        }

        //Main Method
        static void Main()
        {


            //Chapter Zero "Intro"
            Scripts s = new Scripts();
            s.Script(1);
            s.Script(2);
            ReadLine();
            name = input;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            s.Script(3);

            //Chapter One "Combat"
            //Chapter Two "Trading"
            //Chapter Three "Dungeon"
            //Chapter Four "Sailing"
            //Chapter Five "The Edge"
            // Keep the console open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit game.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your class is in a separate namespace, and the existing namespace for program is not using a using statement for including your separate class.

Comment: I mean this is the nicest way possible, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TravisJ it woulnd't compile then, would it?

Comment: @TravisJ Bless you kind sir! I was about to give up and you showed me the way! My code actually runs again and I can get back to it. You have taught me something valuable and I will never forget your kindness to help an idiot who didn't even realize he was in a different namespace. I will name the game's master character after you.

Comment: Wow, thanks :) Glad that worked out for you!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your class is in a separate namespace, and the existing namespace for program is not using a using statement for including your separate class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `static` methods / variables, you shouldn't use the object, you should use the class itself:

```
Program.output = "bla";
Program.WriteLine();
```

instead of

```
p.output = "bla";
p.WriteLine();
```

As your field `p` isn't even initalized, your current code shouldn't compile. If you want to use the object, you should pass it like that:

```
public void Script (int s, Program p)
```

Then you could also make your methods non-static.

Also I'm wondering why you're setting your cursor position to half the length of the text from the right - why not the full offset?

Furthermore you're saying that

> The main issue i had is that when I call the case number in the main method, it only returns the string.

What do you mean by returning the string? Your `Script` method doesn't even have a return type (except for void).

Comment: The namespace thing was the main issue, but this is helpful in other ways! I made a mess of my code and this should help me clean it back up and still maintain current functionality. Your first suggestion there was something I did after fixing namespace as well.